# Capturing webcam image to memory

Tags: c#, .net, memory, webcam, webcam-capture

Is that possible, using .NET C#, to capture image from webcam to memory **without** using disk or form graphical elements (even without any forms)?

Comment: Yes it's possible.

Comment: >Where's your code?< I tried a few ways to get it, but eventually all of that asked about disk or form elements access. So that code parts can be called off-topic.

Comment: >Yes it's possible.< Pleeease, give me code sample, or link to it! :) I think, I am using wrong keywords for search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using EmguCv You can capture and record videos from your webcam. Use the videoWriter to record the frames. You can find more information [here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Video_Files).

Comment: spammer trying to sell something?

Comment: No. Whats makes you think that?